# how to group `http_server_requests_total` metrics on Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I have just instrumented my app and I'd like to show how many hits a certain endpoint has had.

I'm currently using the Ruby client so I get this out of the box already with a certain tags: `host`, `method`, `region`, `instance`, `app`, and `app` is always the same

I don't really care about separate it by region or method, I just want to know how many hits it had, so I did a query like this:

```
http_server_requests_total{app="sumiu-web", path="/metrics"}
```

I see that Prometheus still groups them in different "tags":

[image]

these numbers look right, since a new deployment will spin up a new instance with different tags.

now, I thought I could just `sum` it up but I get a completely different number from what should the total be:

```
sum by(app) (http_server_requests_total{app="sumiu-web", path="/metrics"})
```

[image]

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, the [docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/examples/#using-functions-operators-etc) have a similar function, so I thought this should be ok but apparently it is not...

What is the correct way sum these numbers together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write that "Prometheus still groups them" but the screenshots are from Grafana (not Prometheus) and it's possible behavior between the two may differ.

When you filter a metric by specific labels and values (i.e. `app="sumiu-web"`), you restrict the set of measurements to the subset where that label has that value.

But (!) you do not restrict others labels, so you could, for example, have two measurements where e.g. one measurement is for `app="sumiu-web"` and `region="foo"` and another measurement is for `app="sumiu-web"` and `region="bar"`. These are different measurements.

`sum by(app)` does nothing because you're already limiting measurements to only those where `app="sumiu-web"`.

What you probably want to do is sum values where `app="sumiu-web"` and you don't care (for example) what the value of `region` is. To do this, you can use `without(region)`:

```
sum without(region) (http_server_requests_total{app="sumiu-web", path="/metrics"})
```

Note: You will likely want to include in the `without` all the other labels that apply to the metric `http_server_requests_total` whose different values you don't care about.

Comment: I ended up with something like this: `sum by(app) (increase(http_server_requests_total{app="sumiu-web", method="post", path="/m", code="200"}[24h]))` that also worked...I guess the secret was the `increase` part

Answer (score 1):

The [sum()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) is an [aggregate function](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#aggregate-functions), so it returns sums of the selected time series individually per each point on the graph.

The `sum(http_server_requests_total)` doesn't return the total sum of all the time series with the name `http_server_requests_total` because these time series do not have samples at every data point displayed on the graph - some of them stop receiving new samples, while others just appear and start receiving samples.

So, how to fill gaps in time series with missing datapoints, so they can be `sum()`-ed in an expected way? The only approach is to use [increase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function with the lookbehind window in square brackets covering all the matching time series from the beginning. For example, `sum(increase(http_server_requests_total[1y]))` would return a time series showing the total number of requests over the last year ending at the given point on the graph. In other words, every point on the graph would show the total number of requests over the year-long lookbehind window ending at that point. This approach doesn't scale well, since Prometheus needs to fetch all the raw samples for the matching time series on the given lookbehind window, and then calculate the `increase()` per each point on the graph.

There is more scalable approach exists for alternative Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on - VictoriaMetrics. This system provides two features, which help with sum'ing of multiple metrics of [counter type](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter):

- [running_sum](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#running_sum) is for calculating [running total](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_total) over the selected time range.
- ability to skip lookbehind window in square brackets when calling [rollup functions](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rollup-functions) such as [increase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase). In this case the lookbehind window is automatically set to the interval between points on the graph (aka `step`).

Thanks to these features, the following query returns a time series showing the running total for all the requests over the selected time range on the graph:

```
sum(running_sum(increase(http_server_requests_total)))
```